# hyphenation problem with the character &

Tags: hyphenation, characters

How to produce the hyphenation of the word (BM&FBOVESPA)

I tried to use `\hyphenation{BM\&F-BO-VES-PA}` in the preamble but did not work

Comment: Are you using this "word" often? Otherwise a localized hyphenation would work: `BM\&F\-BO\-VES\-PA`.

Comment: Not only it doesn't work, but it raises an error: `! Not a letter`. In the context of `\hyphenation`, a letter is something that has *nonzero* `\lccode` (and category code 11 or 12, or is produced by `\char`, as is the case with `\&`). This is why David's solution works: it sets a nonzero `\lccode` for `\&`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\lccode`\&`\&
\righthyphenmin2
\hyphenation{BM\&F-BO-VES-PA}

\showhyphens{BM\&FBOVESPA}
\stop
```

Shows that the hyphenation points are as requested:

```
[] \OT1/cmr/m/n/10 BM&F-BO-VES-PA
```

Comment: Are there any dangerous side effects of globally changing the `lccode` of `&` in a LaTeX document?

Comment: @MartinSchröder  The main effect is that `foo&bar` would be considered as one word not two. the lccode doesn't for example affect the use of `&` in tables or in `\ifx` tests.